# How do you say "more moneys"?

Tags: expressions

If I give a bank note of 100 and get back three 20 bills and a bunch of coins, I have less money, but more physical units. How could one express it? Assume an informal setting.

In other languages, one could say something that roughly translates to "I made a good deal, now I have more moneys!", and it would be clear that the total pecuniary worth is less than what I started with.

Comment: I guess you'd say "I have more bills" or "I have more tender".

Comment: Note that, in common use, "money" is (strangely) treated as an "uncountable" value, and, as such, the plural "moneys" (or "monies" -- both are used) is *not* used.  If you have money and get more money you still just have "money", not "moneys".  The plural is used, eg, when discussing different monetary units, as in "the moneys of Iraq, Iran, and Syria ...".

Comment: I think you may have identified a 'weakness' in the English language here. I can't think of an expression that would succinctly describe it. You would have to say something like 'I have more coins and notes' or 'I have more change'.

Comment: @HotLicks  Plural *monies* can have wider uses than you mention. For example *Chairman to Treasurer* Have we received all the various monies from members subscriptions, the annual dinner, sale of goods etc? At least 'monies' is often used like that in the UK, I'm not sure if it is with you. The ODO confirms this use. It means *sums of money*. E.g.*A statement of all moneys paid into and out of an account*.

Comment: @WS2 - Yeah, I forgot that one.

Comment: Does one frequently (in other languages) say such a thing? The closest I can think of is the SNL sketch [First CityWide Change Bank](http://www.hulu.com/watch/4258).

Comment: It sounds like you've identified a joke that doesn't translate well into English.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of racist colloquialisms, but the most common way of describing the exchange of larger denominations for small is to refer to what the need would be:

$100 bill to $20 bills - "Taxi money"

Larger bills to $1 bills - "Stripper money"

Bills to coins - "Parking meter/laundry/vending machine/money" (US)